# Set breakpoint on package in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have big project. I want to suspend execution(begin debug) in condition if began to perform code base from necessary package of source code.

Is it possible in eclipse?

Comment: Do you know how to set breakpoint and debug in eclipse?

Comment: I know how to set breakpoint on line of code

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: I know that performs one in a million class from package. I want to begin debud any of the class from this package

Comment: You can use class loading breakpoint. Keep break point at the class(The class your are interested in i.e one among the MILLION) declaration line. Whenever JVM try's to load this class then execution will be suspended.

Comment: I don't understand you. I have 1 million classes in 1 package. executor uses 1(among million) class randomly. I need to stop in randomly selected class

Comment: Extending @ChandrayyaGK comment, you can use conditional breakpoint to stop only on defined package (`name.startsWith("com.example.mypackage")`).

Comment: You can't randomly select a class to debug without setting a breakpoint before starting the debugging.

Comment: Moritz Petersen, maybe you can show example

Comment: where should I write it?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen Conditional break point can't be used here. Before setting condition you have to put break point, so at this point of time you already know that to which package the given class belongs to event before starting debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Conditional Breakpoint](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F) feature in Eclipse.

For example, you want to trigger the breakpoint whenever a class from your package is loaded:

1. Open type `java.lang.ClassLoader` (`Ctrl-Shift-T` in Eclipse)
2. Go to the method `loadClass(String)`.
3. Set a breakpoint inside of this method:

   ```
   public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
       return loadClass(name, false); <<-- breakpoint here
   }
   ```
4. Right-click on the breakpoint and open Breakpoint Properties.
5. Enable "Conditional" and enter your condition, e.g.:

   ```
   name.startsWith("com.my.company.my.package")
   ```
6. Debug your program.
7. The debugger should break if the condition is true. But you might see an error message:

   > "Conditional breakpoint has compilation error(s) - name cannot be resolved"
8. Solve the error as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F) e.g.:

   ```
   arg0.startsWith("com.my.company.my.package")
   ```
9. Debug your program.

Comment: OK Agreed thanks for clarification + We should attach source for all core Java classes. voting up your answer..